# Javascript alert and redirect in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, redirect, opencart, alert

I am working on the site https://wholesale.garrysun.com (which uses opencart 1.5.4) and trying to add a peice of code that will first redirect them to a login page if they are not logged in as a wholesale customer. If they then try to login and are not registered as a wholesale customer it will tell them that they are in the wrong store, log them out and send them to back to the regular site.

I have gotten everything to work except the message part. I am trying to use the following code but I just get redirected before the message comes up.

```
    <?php 
     if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 1) { /*Check if wholesale store*/
        if (!$logged) { /*Check if user is logged in, not = redirect to login page*/
            $this->redirect('https://wholesale.garrysun.com/index.php?route=account/login'); 
        } else if  ( $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() == '1' ) {  /* Check if user is wholesale user */
 /***************This Works - logs out client and redirects correctly*************/

            /*$this->customer->logout();      
            $this->redirect("https://garrysun.com/");*/
    ?>
 /*******This does NOT Work- gives alert and redirects but the client is not logged out ********/           

<script language="javascript">
                alert("This site is for Wholesale clients only. You will be redirected to our regular site.")
                window.location.href = "https://garrysun.com/";
            </script>
    <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Can anyone show me how to get a message, logout and redirect the customer. If I don't log them out they can't try to log back in unless they clear their browser.

Comment: I would recommend using server side authentication here.

Comment: how can I do that, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: You'll have to look it up, I don't know what backend you're using. It looks like Wordpress and I'm not super familiar with that, but there should be a lot of people who are!

Comment: As I said in the title and the post, I am using OpenCart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 1) {
if (!$logged) {
$this->redirect('https://wholesale.garrysun.com/index.php?route=account/login');
} else if  ( $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() == '1' ) { ?>

<script src="Where Javascript goes"> // or just use the <script> tag
function alertUser() {
  if (window.confirm(‘put stuff here’)) {
    window.location.href=‘put link here’;
  }
}
</script>

<?php 
$this->customer->logout();
echo "<script>alertUser();</script>;" } } ?>
```

Hope this works for you, however I have not de bugged it.

Comment: This doesn't log them out and if they hit ok it will let them back to the site. If they navigate quickly they can continue to browse. Is there anyway to remove the ok button or redirect on OK?

Comment: My bad I forgot this: `$this->customer->logout();` I edited my previous post. That should take care of logout. instead of alert use this: `if (window.confirm(‘put stuff here’)) {
        window.location.href=‘put link here’;
    } else { var x = ""; }`

Comment: I just figured that out too. Works great! Thanks!